# WPF MVVM design ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I have the following model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public City City {get;set;}
}

public class City
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I have two Views:

- One for display all Persons with LastName and the Name of the city in
  a DataGrid(AllPersonsViewModel)
- One for adding a new Person (PersonViewModel)

My AllPersonsViewModel:

```
public class AllPersonViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> PersonViewModels {get;set;}
}
```

I started with the following PersonViewModel:

```
public class PersonViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private Person _person;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _person.Name;}
        set { _person.Name = value; RaisePropertyChange("Name");}
    }

    public string CityName
    {
        get { return _person.City.Name;}
    }
}
```

Then I added the properties for adding a new Person. In the View I need a Textbox for the PersonName and a Combobox for selection of a City:

```
public class PersonViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private Person _person;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _person.Name;}
        set { _person.Name = value; RaisePropertyChange("Name");}
    }

    public string CityName
    {
        get { return _person.City.Name;}        
    }

    public City SelectedCity 
    { 
        get { return _person.City;}
        set { _person.City = value; RaisePropertyChange("SelectedCity");}
    }

    public ObservableCollection<City> Cities {get;set;} 
}
```

Is this the right approach? It seems a little bit redundant to me. In the Grid of AllPersonsView I could also bind directly to the "SelectedCity.Name" instead of the extra property CityName. The grid is also readonly.

Comment: And what is your question, again?

Comment: Last Paragraph: "Is this the right approach? It seems a little bit redundant to me. In the Grid of AllPersonsView I could also bind directly to the "SelectedCity.Name" instead of the extra property CityName."

Comment: Yes, I can read. My point is that your question is very vague... Is there a wrong or right approach here? If it works, it's probably right, if not, then it's probably wrong. I don't think that Cities should be a property of a Person though.

Answer (score 2):

you have multiple problems;

1 - you do not need to declare an observable collection of viewmodels in `AllPersonViewModel`. Just declare an ObservableCollection of `Person`.

2 - do not add the `CityName` property; not needed as you have stated.

3- do not add the `Name` property. Bind the textbox to Name property of the `Person`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For 3 I must add INotifyPropertyChanged to my Person model, right?

Comment: @LuckyStrike yes; if you are not binding ObservableCollections, you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 1):

Your question really boils down "is it OK to expose my model directly to the view?" Some purist will say no while other will say that having a view model that wraps a model without adding any new functionality is redundant.

In my opinion it depends on the task at hand but "skiping" a view model may come back and bite you later when you need to add additional state that doesn't belong in the model. If in doubt use a view model but for instance when exposing simple model objects in a list you often don't need the extra layer the view model provides.

In your case you have opted for the "purist" solution and because your model object doesn't support `INotifyPropertyChanged` you can't get rid of the view model if a model property is changed by multiple sources. But instead of providing a `CityName` property you could bind to `SelectedCity.Name`. WPF supports property navigation in data binding expressions.

For more insight into this topic you can google [mvvm expose model](https://www.google.com/search?q=mvvm%20expose%20model).